# Finding the transfinite diameter of the level sets of complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, conformal-geometry, potential-theory

Given a simply-connected domain $|g(z)|\ge C$ how can I find the analytic conformal mapping guaranteed by the Riemann mapping theorem?

In particular I'm interested in finding the transfinite diameter of the domain $|\log z|\le C$ as a function of $C$. As I understand it—I had to look up the terms—this means finding a function $f$ mapping the closure of the exterior $|\log z|\ge C$ to the unit disk, with $f(\infty)=0$, and the the answer I want will be $f'(\infty).$

So what conformal mapping $f$ sends $|\log z|\ge C$ to the unit disk, or (if it's easier) what is $f'(\infty)$?

**Edit:** Hagen correctly pointed out that there are issues with $\log z$ near $\pi$. For my application you can assume that $0<C<3.$ In fact probably $C<1.$

**Edit:** I don't have a scan of the section of the paper this comes from, but here's the rough translation I wrote into my notes:

> If $f(x)$ is an entire function, $S$ is the circle $|S|\le\gamma,$ the transform $T$ is the domain $|\log z|\le\gamma,$ and the transfinite diameter $\tau$ grows with $\gamma$ and is equal to 1 for $\gamma=\gamma_0=0.843\ldots,$ then [the desired result obtains.]

I did not write out the proof (or a translation) but it said very little, essentially just that $\gamma_0$ was what you got when you set the transfinite diameter to 1. It did not give the mapping or give any further information.

Comment: At least on inexpensive book on conformal mappings, Nehari i think. http://store.doverpublications.com/048661137x.html  ALSO http://store.doverpublications.com/048643236x.html  MAYBE http://store.doverpublications.com/0486640256.html

Comment: @WillJagy: (looking at Amazon preview) The Riemann mapping theorem is buried pretty deep in chapter 5 of that book, and I know nothing of the material in chapters 1, 4, and 5 (my complex analysis course covered chapters 2 and 3 pretty well I think). So maybe learning enough material to solve this problem isn't practical.

Comment: Could be.  meanwhile, some specific mappings  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping   although your transfinite diameter seems to involve a good deal more machinery

Comment: @WillJagy: I read that page, plus the Wikipedia and MathWorld pages on the Riemann mapping theorem and conformal maps. I can see how to verify the mappings but not how to create them _ex nihilo_.

Comment: I think there are significant issues with the logarithm having a branch cut along some ray from the origin. In general finding the exact map for a specific set is unlikely. As I recall the proof is only of existence, and offers little insight on the form.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: My particular example comes from a research paper I read which gives no explanation of the map, just a calculation of what the transfinite diameter comes to with certain $C$. Because it omitted all details I supposed that this was considered routine. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: All details? Doesn't sound like much of a paper. Try asking the author(s). Nicely, of course.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: The author, Pisot, died 30 years ago. The paper is Sur les fonctions arithmétiques analytiques à croissance exponentielle, _C. R. Acad. Sc. Paris_ 222 and the result is on p. 988.

Comment: Maybe your regions are sufficiently "disklike" that you can approximate it with an inscribed and a circumscribed disk?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I don't think so. The point is to find the transfinite diameter for a given $C$ and adjust the value of $C$ until the transfinite diameter is at a desired value, and the distance between the bounding disks that I'd only get ~1 decimal place of accuracy if I did that.

Comment: I really wanted to take a look at the paper, but it does not seem to be available online. Any chance you could post the relevant fragment in case it gives a clue to the author's thoughts? I understand that we are to take $\log 1=1$ and look at a domain (most of it in right half plane) containing $1$.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: I added my personal translation (all I have) of the relevant excerpt.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that conformal map is not a way to go. The transfinite diameter / logarithmic capacity / Chebyshev constant (all the same thing) can be estimated in other ways, by constructing appropriate finite subsets (approx. Fekete sets), measures, or polynomials. I think this is what Pisot did, with a lot of tedious numerics. Later authors citing the result reproduce $0.843...$ with no mention of how it was obtained. E.g., Kahane in *On a Theorem of Pólya*.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: Maybe you can expand this into an answer?

Comment: [This article by Pisot](http://digreg.mathguide.de/cgi-bin/ssgfi/anzeige.pl?db=reg&ci=JbDMV&id=ART&sd=y1942v52p?&nr=050068&ew=SSGFI) has similar calculations. He works with polynomials of certain kind, approximating the set of interest by the lemniscate $\{|p|\le 1\}$. The capacity of such a lemniscate is the modulus of the leading coefficient of $p$ raised to power $1/n$.

Comment: I posted some computer-assisted computations which show the constant is 0.84383...: [Pisot constant beyond 0.843](https://calculus7.org/2017/06/17/pisot-constant-beyond-0-843/)

Comment: @Guero That is very interesting to me -- would you be willing to email me at charles.greathouse@case.edu to discuss briefly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is amusing to observe that all later authors citing Pisot's result reproduce $0.843\dots$ with the same number of digits (Google Search for *Pisot 0.843* turned up a few). None of them commented on how the number came about. A clue to Pisot's method may be found in the paper *Über ganzwertige ganze Funktionen* (1942) where he experiments with polynomials $p(z)=(z-1)^a(z-2)^b(z^2-3z+3)^c$ arriving at $a=6,  b=2, c=1$ presumably by trial and error. These are polynomials with roots around $1$, and the idea is that the level sets of $p$ approximate the level sets of logarithm.  This particular polynomial does not give precise bounds for transfinite diameter of level set. I still don't know how Pisot found $0.843\dots$ so precisely without computers; it's likely that his method was more sophisticated than what I present below.

A key fact about transfinite diameter is that for any monic polynomial $p$ of degree $n$, the transfinite diameter of the set $E_\lambda=\{z:|p(z)|\le \lambda\}$ is equal to $\lambda^{1/n}$. The proof can be found, for example, in *Potential theory in the complex plane* by Ransford. For the special case when $E_\lambda$ is connected (which is the only one needed here) it suffices to observe that $(p(z)/\lambda)^{1/n}$ has a single-valued branch in the complement of $E_\lambda$, and maps the complement onto the exterior of unit disk. At infinity this function is asymptotic to $z/\lambda^{1/n}$, hence the result.

Also, the transfinite diameter is monotone with respect to inclusion. Therefore, if $E$ is any set and $p$ is a monic polynomial such that $E_\lambda \subset E\subset E_\mu$, then we know the transfinite diameter of $E$ is between $\lambda^{1/n}$ and $\mu^{1/n}$.

So, to estimate the transfinite diameter of the set $\{e^z:|z|\le r\}$, we must come up with polynomials that have all roots within this set and have nearly constant modulus on its boundary. I take $r=0.843$ for illustration. The set is shown below.

[image: set]

Pretty round, but with noticeable flatness on the left, and somewhat stretched out vertically. The flatness tells me to put some vertically spaces zeros on the left. On the right I might want to have a real zero. (Or not...) By trial and error, I found a fifth degree polynomial with decent fit: blue curve is the set $|p|=1$, the red curve is as above.

[image: fit]

The roots, marked above, $0.985\pm 0.46i$, $ 1.51\pm 0.51i$, and $ 1.79$. The blue curve is $|p|=1$ (`implicitplot` in Maple).

To quantify the quality of fit,  look at the values $\{|p(e^z)|^{1/5}: |z|=0.843\}$. Computer tells me they are between $0.992$ and $1.005$. Hence, the transfinite diameter lies between these numbers as well.

One possible way to improve precision is to use multiple roots, like Pisot did.

---

As an aside, [Thomas Ransford](http://www2.ulaval.ca/fileadmin/ulaval_ca/Images/recherche/bd/chercheur/fiche/401650.html), the author of aforementioned book, is  an expert in high-precision computation of transfinite diameter (aka logarithmic capacity).